# '=' : cannot convert from 'CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>::Node *' to 'Node *'

Tags: c++

I have Node* current where I store a pointer to what node that is current at "top" of the list. When I set a new node as current I get the error:

```
'=' : cannot convert from 'CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>::Node *' to 'Node *'
while compiling class template member function 'void CircularDoubleDirectedList<int>::addAtCurrent(const T &)' with [ T=int ]
```

It is the three rows with //Problem comment that generates those errors if take them away everything works fine.

```
#include "ICircularDoubleDirectedList.h"

template <typename T> class CircularDoubleDirectedList;
class Node;

template <typename T>
class CircularDoubleDirectedList :
    public ICircularDoubleDirectedList<T>{
public:
    //Variables
    Node* current;
    int nrOfElements;
    direction currentDirection;

    //Functions
    CircularDoubleDirectedList();
    ~CircularDoubleDirectedList();
    void addAtCurrent(const T& element) override;

private:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        T data;
        Node* forward;
        Node* backward;

        Node(const T& element);
    };

};
template <typename T>
void CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::addAtCurrent(const T& element){
    Node* newNode = new Node(element);
    newNode->data = element;
    if (this->nrOfElements == 0){
        newNode->forward = newNode;
        newNode->backward = newNode;
    }
    else{
        this->current->forward = newNode; // Problem
        this->current->forward->backward = newNode; // Problem
    }
    this->current = newNode; //Problem
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to declare the private `Node` class before you use it in the public interface?  And are you sure you want `current` as a public member variable in the first place?  In fact, all the member variables should be private, shouldn't they?  You don't want someone using the class tinkering with the number of items, or setting the `current` to a node in a different list, or … otherwise abusing your template class.

Comment: I hade declared it I just missed the top part of my code. Yea sure they maybe should be private. I just want this to work in the first place.

Comment: Your code has some trivial errors (like forward declaration of Node), when corrected compiles your code. Refer [Demo](http://ideone.com/qmRCEN)

Comment: Comments are for comments, answers go in answers.

Comment: @Barry: I don;t see an answer here. Even the one your posted does not seem to answer OPs question. It still doesn't explain, how OP gets the mysterious compile error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you forward declare `Node` as being outside of the class here:

```
template <typename T> class CircularDoubleDirectedList;
class Node;
```

That is declaring a type `Node` in the global namespace. It is `::Node`. Then, within your class declaration, `current` takes on *that* type:

```
template <typename T>
class CircularDoubleDirectedList 
    : public ICircularDoubleDirectedList<T>
{
public:
    Node* current;   // this is a pointer to ::Node.
};
```

Then you provide a declaration of `CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::Node`. This is **not** the same type as `::Node`. It also gets looked up first by name resolution rules. So in here:

```
template <typename T>
void CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::addAtCurrent(const T& element){
    Node* newNode = new Node(element); // newNode is a pointer to
                                       // CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::Node
```

But `current` is a pointer to the still-incomplete type `::Node`. Hence the error - you have inadvertently created *two* types named `Node`.

If you're going to forward-declare `Node`, you have to do it *inside* the class:

```
template <typename T>
class CircularDoubleDirectedList 
    : public ICircularDoubleDirectedList<T>
{
    class Node; // NOW it's CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::Node
};
```

Comment: I had class Node; declared I just missed the top part where I put it. However I put it at the top before My list class, should i have it inside the class instead ?

Comment: @Olof: don't show an approximation to the code that generates the error.  Show an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea — that reproduces exactly the error you want analyzed.  We can't reliably tell you what's going wrong in your code if you don't show your code; at best, we can guess.

Comment: @Olof NOW that you posted a complete question, I can give you a better answer.